# What is the &= operator for in Java

Tags: java

The Java tutorials [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) mention that `&=` is an assignment operator but doesn't seem to mention what it does.

What does `&=` do?

Comment: Whoops, it's the page before, updated it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
a &= x
```

is equivalent to

```
a = (type of a)(a & x)
```

which in turn is a

- [bitwise AND](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) of `a` and `x` in the case where `a` and `x` are integers or a
- non [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) logical AND in the case of `a` and `x` being `boolean`s (which means that `x` will be evaluated in any case here, even if `a` is `false`).

There are several other binary operators which can be used with similar semantics, like `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `|=`, `<<=`, ...

Comment: Also the non short-circuiting logical 'and' in the case of `boolean`s.